# opening up a server location from a websitse

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, salesforce, apex-code

GOAL:

I have a business request that wants us to create a link so the user can open a server directory (in a file manager window) from a link on our website. We want them to stay on the same IE page.  FWIW- this is in our salesforce environment

PROBLEM:

I am getting an irritating defect. That is, that the file manager window is opening up to a server, but i'm also getting a blank IE window to open up, which is a poor user experience.

Can someone help me with a way around this artifact?

Comment: 2 things.  1: This is a horrible security idea.  2. Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: hmm, maybe HTML iFrame with javascript?

Comment: @ben336 ---The security concerns are mitigated-  we require authentication to get to the website then the user needs to be on the VPN to access the server. Then, the user has to have privilages to that folder.

Comment: @JanCzarny, can you point me to a reference?